# Sqoop Import String hash value has special character

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

Sqoop Import String hash value has special character and is failing with following exception.

*2016-05-10 16:49:00,506 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] db.DBRecordReader (DBRecordReader.java:executeQuery(110)) - Executing query:  SELECT JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.SHIPPING_GROUP_ID, JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.STR_ID, JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.FRST_NM, JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.LAST_NM, JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.CNTCT_PHN_NB, JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.TEXT_ALERT_MOBILE_NB, JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.EMAIL_ID, JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.IS_PRIM_PICKUP_IN FROM DT_PRD_CORE.JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO, DT_PRD_CORE.DCSPP_SHIP_GROUP, DT_PRD_CORE.DCSPP_ORDER WHERE JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.SHIPPING_GROUP_ID=DCSPP_SHIP_GROUP.SHIPPING_GROUP_ID AND DCSPP_SHIP_GROUP.ORDER_REF=DCSPP_ORDER.ORDER_ID AND ( JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.SHIPPING_GROUP_ID >= 'sg10038415' ) AND ( JCP_STR_CNTCT_INFO.SHIPPING_GROUP_ID < 'sg31쀰耲䀶4䀲'' ) 
2016-05-10 16:49:00,535 ERROR [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] db.DBRecordReader (LoggingUtils.java:logAll(43)) - Top level exception: 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:886)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.executeQuery(DBRecordReader.java:111)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-10 16:49:00,554 INFO  [Thread-665] mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper (ProgressThread.java:run(158)) - Auto-progress thread is finished. keepGoing=false*

Answer (score 0):

IN sqoop you can change character set importing data using following parameter

```
--default-character-set=<your character set>
```

I would suggest you to check your Oracle database character set and try to set it accordingly in above sqoop parameter

Source: [Sqoop Document](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html)